# How to include .cs files in nunit test runner framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, automated-tests, nunit

The test input in nunit framework(2.6.4) takes .dll and .exe files for testing. Can i test classes and methods in nunit framework using the .cs file and not its .dll or .exe version?If yes then How?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: This question is a bit vague, but if you have your tests in a project in the same solution as the rest of your code, you could simply add a project reference from your test project by right-clicking your test project -> add -> reference. That should allow you to easily debug the code while running your tests.

Answer (score 1):

> Can i test classes and methods in nunit framework using the .cs file
>   and not its .dll or .exe version?

No. You will have to compile the `.cs` file(s) into a DLL or an EXE or similar. NUnit will not do that for you.

(In general, you do not "run" C# code without first compiling it into the intermediate language CIL (byte code). After that, the run-rime will just-in-time translate the CIL to whatever native instructions are used by the hardware.)

However, there exists plugins for Visual Studio which will both compile the C# and start NUnit with one click in the relevant source file.

Comment: Could you please tell me more on the plugins that will compile the c# as well as start nunit.

Comment: @learner One I know of is [ReSharper (R#)](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). I think there are others.

Comment: You could also use the free [NUnit 3 test adapter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnit3TestAdapter) add-on for Visual Studio. Your NUnit tests should then show up in the Unit Test Explorer.